# ManyToMany Hibernate save related object

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm learning Spring JPA and I started with mapping Objects in to tables. I got no problem with OneToOne and OneToMany relation, but I can't quite understand why I fail to presist an objects releted with ManyToMany relation.
I got a Book that can have many Author and an Author that can have many Book.
The schema get generated corectly (I can see it in MySql Workbench) with the intermediate table book_author, but I get this exeption:

Hibernate: insert into author (first_name, last_name) values (?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into book (kind, title) values (?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into book (kind, title) values (?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into author_book (author_id, book_id) values (?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into author_book (author_id, book_id) values (?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into author (first_name, last_name) values (?, ?)

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.demo.models.Book; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.demo.models.Book

I pasted also the Hibernate operation that get fine.

Those are my entities definition:

```
@Table(name = "author")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "author_book",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")}
            )
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();

    //getters and setters omitted for brevity
}

@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String kind;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books")
    private List<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>();

    //getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

And those are my repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Long> {

}

@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {

}
```

And finally this is my main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        AuthorRepository authorRepository = ctx.getBean(AuthorRepository.class);
        BookRepository bookRepository = ctx.getBean(BookRepository.class);

        Author author = new Author();
        author.setFirstName("Author");
        author.setLastName("First");

        Author author2 = new Author();
        author.setFirstName("Author");
        author.setLastName("Second");

        Book book1 = new Book();
        book1.setTitle("Book 1");
        book1.setKind("History");
        book1.getAuthors().add(author);
        book1.getAuthors().add(author2);

        Book book2 = new Book();
        book2.setTitle("Book 2");
        book2.setKind("Science");
        book2.getAuthors().add(author);

        author.getBooks().add(book1);
        author.getBooks().add(book2);
        author2.getBooks().add(book1);

        authorRepository.save(author);
        authorRepository.save(author2);

        System.out.println("-->End of db operation");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new method in the `Author` class to add the `book` instead of using `author.getBooks().add(book1)`

```java
    public void addBook(Book book) {
        books.add(book);
        books.authors.add(this);
    }
```

And also you should not be using `CascadeType.ALL` because when removing the entity other side of the relation is also removed

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate maintains 3 states for an object:

1. Transient: Newly created object
2. Persistent: When the Hibernate saves an object
3. Detached: After an object is saved and the session is closed

In your case, the authorRepository saves the transient object (author, book1, and book2) and closes the session after saving them. So, all the objects (author, book1, and book2) are in the detached state after the first call of save method and that is the reason when you try to save author2, Hibernate throws the detached entity exception. You can find more information in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjZGFHEdD4M&list=PL4AFF701184976B25&index=25